# Incompatible Java method

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to learn Java through a tutorial on Aide and have entered what I believed was the correct code:

```
package com.aide.trainer.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set main.xml as user interface layout
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTextView1);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainButton1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View p1)
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTextView1);
                textView.setText("Clicked");
            }
        });
        button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View p1)
            {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

But at `public void onLongClick(View p1)`, there is an error around `void` that says:

> The type of this method is incompatible with the type of the overridden method 'android.view.View.OnLongClickListener.onLongClick(android.view.View)'

I can't figure out what I did wrong.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an [`OnLongClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html), `onLongClick(…)` must return `boolean`, not `void`.

Comment: Nailed it, I owe you my sanity